How do I put long strings into the Blob column using DBeaver's import csv
I'm trying to load the csv file to oracleDB using DBeaver's "import csv" function.
The data you want to put in is a very long string type csv cell, and the type of OracleDB is a BLOB type.
However, since i can't put the String in the BLOB, i'm going to convert the String into binary and Hex.
df['long_string'].apply(lambda x:x.encode('utf-8').hex() if x is not None else x) 
df.to_csv(filename, index=False, header=True,encoding='utf-8-sig',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

In this case, the value in the Long_string column is so long that the data is truncated, and the rest is pushed to the next row.
How can I get a long string into a BLOB well?
There is no binary and HEX conversion of specific columns in dbeaver's import csv function, so I decided to convert the data in the csv cell directly.

Why are you using Python to write data to CSV and then importing the CSV using DBeaver? Why don't you connect Python to the database and insert the data directly from Python (skipping the conversion to hexadecimals, CSV, DBeaver, which seems to be the part that is giving you issues)?
